# Unsure how to resolve this Bottle error (Python)

Tags: python, import, bottle

Here are my imports:

```
from bottle import request, route, run, template, static_file, redirect
from urllib2 import urlopen, URLError, Request
from pymongo import MongoClient
from config.development import config
import json
```

And here is the offending line (and another line that I think may be causing an issue):

```
game_id = request.forms.get('game_id')
request = Request(config['singlegame_url'].replace('$GAMEID', game_id))
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
UnboundLocalError("local variable 'request' referenced before assignment",)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bottle.py", line 862, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bottle.py", line 1732, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
  File "app.py", line 23, in add
    game_id = request.forms.get('game_id')
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'request' referenced before assignment
```

My first thought was that the two `request` modules were causing issues, but I couldn't get the error to go away by messing around with the imports and importing stuff `as` another name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must rename your `request` variable to something else.

Python kind of reserves the variable name `request` to be a local variable due to `request = ...` before actually executing the code.
The interpreter then executes your line `game_id = request.forms.get('game_id')`, where `request` is the new reserved local variable, which is, undefined.

Here's a good example of the same issue:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> def f():
...     print(x)  # You'd think this prints 1, but `x` is the local variable now
...     x = 3

>>> f()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module>
    f()
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 2, in f
    print(x)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'x' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: I imagine I'd also have to change the name of one of the request modules? I have one from `bottle` and one from `urllib2`.

Comment: @maxmackie Python is case sensitive, so `Request` is not the same as `request`. Therefore you don't have to change the name :)